# I have n number of li, if its ordering number(position, starts from 1) is divided by 2 then update "two" in that li's text using pure css/css3

Tags: html, css

- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 

output-

- 
- two
- 
- two

so on..
is it possible without using javascript or jquery

Comment: Why don't you want to use javascript?

Comment: yes through the js it is quite easy, but there was a interview question to do that through css.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at nth-child selectors.

You can change the content of HTML tags with CSS (look at content: tag), but CSS is not intended for this task.